# asp.net json.net parse results

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json.net

I´m not familiar with JSON data parsing. So far, this is what I´ve come up to through web research:
data to parse:
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/

I´m trying to use the JSON.NET/VB.NET framework to do so:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

'(inside a function)
Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/")
strResult As String = json.SelectToken("streams").SelectToken("game")
```

It´s returning me an error message, and I´m sure I don´t have the structure right. How could I make this work? And afterwards, I´d like to loop through the results of the returning array.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going (just a conceptual example - console, not asp.net):

```
Dim json As JObject = _
    JObject.Parse(New WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"))

If json IsNot Nothing AndAlso json.HasValues Then

   If json.SelectTokens("streams") IsNot Nothing _
      AndAlso json.SelectTokens("streams").Children().Any() Then

      Dim games() As JToken = json.SelectTokens("streams").Children().ToArray()

      For Each child As JToken In games

          Console.WriteLine("game title: {0} game id: {1} for mature audience? {2}", _
                                      child.Item("game"), child.Item("_id"), child.Item("channel").Item("mature"))
          Console.WriteLine()
      Next

      Console.ReadLine()
   End If

End If
```

Hth....

Comment: Cool...thanks...that really helped me. I´ve modified the code a bit for the newbies (like myself), just to be a bit clear:

    For Each child As JToken In games



    
     lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "game=" & child.Item("game").ToString() & "<br>"
     lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "channel.views=" & child.Item("channel").Item("followers").ToString() & "<br>"
     lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "channel._links.teams=" & child.Item("channel").Item("_links").Item("teams").ToString() & "<br>"
     

    Next

Answer (score -1):

This is the code simplified, with the help of EdSF, for the newbies in json (like myself):

```
    Dim apiURL As String = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=10&offset=0"
    Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(New WebClient().DownloadString(apiURL))

    If json IsNot Nothing AndAlso json.HasValues Then

        If json.SelectTokens("streams") IsNot Nothing AndAlso json.SelectTokens("streams").Children().Any() Then

            Dim games() As JToken = json.SelectTokens("streams").Children().ToArray()

            For Each child As JToken In games

                'Console.WriteLine("game title: {0} game id: {1} for mature audience? {2}", child.Item("game"), child.Item("_id"), child.Item("channel").Item("mature"))
                'Console.WriteLine()

                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "_id=" & child.Item("_id").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "game=" & child.Item("game").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "viewers=" & child.Item("viewers").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "preview=" & child.Item("preview").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "preview.small=" & child.Item("preview").Item("small").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "<img src='" & child.Item("preview").Item("small").ToString() & "'/><br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "_links.self=" & child.Item("_links").Item("self").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "channel.status=" & child.Item("channel").Item("status").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "channel.logo=" & child.Item("channel").Item("logo").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "<img src='" & child.Item("channel").Item("logo").ToString() & "'/><br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "channel.video_banner=" & child.Item("channel").Item("video_banner").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "channel.url=" & child.Item("channel").Item("url").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "channel.views=" & child.Item("channel").Item("followers").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "channel._links.self=" & child.Item("channel").Item("_links").Item("self").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "channel._links.teams=" & child.Item("channel").Item("_links").Item("teams").ToString() & "<br>"
                lblMensagemSucesso.Text &= "<br>"

            Next

            'Console.ReadLine()
        End If

    End If
```

Comment: Instead of concatenating strings and updating the UI for each line, it would be far better to use a StringBuilder to construct the string and update the UI only once at the end.