# vb.net json.net parse results

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parsing, json.net

I would like to get the amount of viewers on an online stream.

Right now this stream is online https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ludendi

For reference, the JSON from the above URL looks like this:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ludendi",
        "channel": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ludendi"
    },
    "stream": {
        "_id": 9911305984,
        "game": "The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask",
        "viewers": 3848,
        "preview": {
            "small": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_ludendi-80x50.jpg",
            "medium": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_ludendi-320x200.jpg",
            "large": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_ludendi-640x400.jpg",
            "template": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_ludendi-{width}x{height}.jpg"
        },
        "_links": {
            "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ludendi"
        },
        "channel": {
            "mature": false,
            "abuse_reported": null,
            "status": "Team Ludendi presents speedrunning at DreamHack Summer 2014!",
            "display_name": "Ludendi",
            "game": "The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask",
            "delay": 0,
            "_id": 28673774,
            "name": "ludendi",
            "created_at": "2012-03-03T13:23:16Z",
            "updated_at": "2014-06-15T14:46:58Z",
            "logo": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ludendi-profile_image-e427022cc9f86446-300x300.png",
            "banner": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ludendi-channel_header_image-f33cb42afafa213c-640x125.jpeg",
            "video_banner": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ludendi-channel_offline_image-821fc3728572551f-640x360.jpeg",
            "background": null,
            "profile_banner": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ludendi-profile_banner-81f7a981e4b461a9-480.png",
            "profile_banner_background_color": null,
            "url": "http://www.twitch.tv/ludendi",
            "views": 5501318,
            "followers": 15749,
            "_links": {
                "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ludendi",
                "follows": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ludendi/follows",
                "commercial": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ludendi/commercial",
                "stream_key": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ludendi/stream_key",
                "chat": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/ludendi",
                "features": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ludendi/features",
                "subscriptions": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ludendi/subscriptions",
                "editors": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ludendi/editors",
                "teams": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ludendi/teams",
                "videos": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ludendi/videos"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner, so I tried to modify the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214121/asp-net-json-net-parse-results), but it isn't working for me.
Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim json As JObject = _
JObject.Parse(New WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams"))

    If json IsNot Nothing AndAlso json.HasValues Then

        If json.SelectTokens("stream") IsNot Nothing _
           AndAlso json.SelectTokens("stream").Children().Any() Then

            Dim games() As JToken = json.SelectTokens("stream").Children().ToArray()

            For Each child As JToken In games

                MsgBox(child.Item("viewers"))
            Next
        End If

    End If
 End If
```

With the help of Brian Rogers i tried this:

```
    Dim json As String =
        New WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ludendi")

    Dim root As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)

    Dim streams As JToken = root("stream")
    If streams IsNot Nothing Then

        For Each stream As JToken In streams.Children()

            Dim id As String = stream("_id").ToString()
            Dim game As String = stream("game").ToString()
            Dim viewers As String = stream("viewers").ToString()


            MsgBox(game)
            MsgBox(viewers)

        Next

    End If
```

But i got an error `InvalidOperationException` on this line:

```
            Dim id As String = stream("_id").ToString()
```

Comment: Please show your work so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.  This is the minimum code you need to get the game and viewers for a specific stream.

```
Dim json As String = New WebClient() _
    .DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ludendi")

Dim root As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)

Dim stream As JToken = root("stream")

Dim game As String = stream("game").ToString()
Dim viewers As String = stream("viewers").ToString()

MsgBox(game & " (" & viewers & ")")
```

This will display `The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask (3609 viewers)`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. but what I want is to get informations on a specific stream. So I need to use a specific url.

This one is online righ now ( https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/ludendi )

When i try to modify your code, it doesn't work

Comment: The reason my code did not work when you changed the URL is because the JSON is different between the two URLs.  The former URL `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams` returns JSON containing an array of streams, so you need a loop to process them.  The JSON for an individual stream does not have the `streams` array, so the stream info is one level higher in the JSON and you don't need a loop.  I've edited my answer to show the minimum code to retrieve the game and viewers for a single specific stream.