# Organizing data using JSON.NET in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I want to start off by saying that I have no idea what I am doing. I am trying to read json data from Twitch.tv. The URL I am currently working with looks like this: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/seeingblue/follows

Inside my program I have managed to deserialize my data and make it look neat and readable. I'm having trouble storing the data is an organized fashion. What I want to do is poll the URL on a regular interval and check for any changes.

I was able to get this example to work, but I can't modify the code to work for what I need.
[vb.net json.net parse results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225918/vb-net-json-net-parse-results)

This is what I currently have:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try
        Dim json As String = New WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/seeingblue/follows?limit=1&offset=0")
        Dim root As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
        Dim stream As JToken = root("user")
        Dim game As String = stream("name").ToString()
        'Dim viewers As String = stream("_links").ToString()
        MsgBox(game)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End Try

End Sub
```

But I just get an error about `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

or if I try

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Try
        Dim json As String = New WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/seeingblue/follows?limit=1&offset=0")
        Dim root As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
        Dim stream As JToken = root("follows")
        Dim game As String = stream("created_at").ToString()
        'Dim viewers As String = stream("_links").ToString()
        MsgBox(game)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End Try

End Sub
```

I get an error stating `Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "created_at". Array position index expected.` Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't index arrays by strings.

Comment: So I guess the difference between the two is the example is not an array and mine is. Any idea how I can do this then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to look at the formatted JSON.  I pasted the URL from your code into the validator window at [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) and clicked "Validate".  Here is the result:

```
{
    "follows": [
        {
            "created_at": "2014-10-02T17:15:10Z",
            "_links": {
                "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/sleepyynet/follows/channels/seeingblue"
            },
            "user": {
                "_id": 41403351,
                "name": "sleepyynet",
                "created_at": "2013-03-16T19:42:01Z",
                "updated_at": "2014-10-07T19:28:33Z",
                "_links": {
                    "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/sleepyynet"
                },
                "display_name": "SleepyyNet",
                "logo": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/sleepyynet-profile_image-96061b55b0da4c11-300x300.png",
                "bio": "Zzz...The Tired One",
                "type": "user"
            }
        }
    ],
    "_total": 14,
    "_links": {
        "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/seeingblue/follows?direction=DESC&limit=1&offset=0",
        "next": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/seeingblue/follows?direction=DESC&limit=1&offset=1"
    }
}
```

You can see from the above that the JSON response object contains three properties: `follows`, `_total`, and `_links`.  The `follows` property contains an array.  That array contains an object, which has three properties: `created_at`, `_links` and `user`.  `created_at` is a string containing a date, while `user` and `_links` are both objects containing yet more properties.

With this in mind let's look at what your code is doing.

In your first example, you're doing this:

```
Dim stream As JToken = root("user")
Dim game As String = stream("name").ToString()
```

This fails because there is no `user` property at the root level of the JSON, so `root("user")` returns null.  You get an exception when you attempt to use the null `stream` variable on the following line.

In your second example, you're doing this:

```
Dim stream As JToken = root("follows")
Dim game As String = stream("created_at").ToString()
```

This fails because `root("follows")` returns an array.  You can't index a `JArray` with a string name; you must use a numeric index (or else iterate over the array using a `For Each` loop).

---

So how can we make this work?  Let's take your first example.  To get the name of the user in the first item of the follows array in the root of the response, you could do this:

```
Dim root As JToken = JToken.Parse(json)    ' Parse the response
Dim follows As JToken = root("follows")    ' Get the "follows" array from the root
Dim item As JToken = follows(0)            ' Get the first item of the array
Dim user As JToken = item("user")          ' Get the user object from the item
Dim name As String = user("name")          ' Get the name from the user object
MsgBox(name)                               ' Display the name
```

Another way to do the same thing with less code is to use the handy `SelectToken` method to navigate directly to the desired `JToken` using a path syntax:

```
Dim root As JToken = JToken.Parse(json)
Dim name As String = root.SelectToken("follows[0].user.name")
MsgBox(name)
```

Of course, both of the above examples assume that you already have the index of array item you want.  If there's only one item, no problem-- the index is `0`.  But what if there are multiple items in the array?  In that case, you'll probably want to do your processing in a loop instead.  Here's an example which will display the names of all users following "seeingblue".

```
Dim url As String = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/seeingblue/follows"
Dim json As String = New WebClient().DownloadString(url)
Dim root As JToken = JToken.Parse(json)
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

For Each item As JToken In root("follows")
    sb.AppendLine(item.SelectToken("user.name"))
Next

MsgBox(sb.ToString())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, very easy to understand. I will hash over this for a few hours and I'm sure I can get something working out of it.